# Configure RabbitMQ host and port from a config.properties file

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

In [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/) page, I can see that the host and port of the RabbitMQ can be configured in the XML Application Context file ass following:

```
<rabbit:connection-factory
id="connectionFactory" host="somehost" port="5672"/>
```

I want to take the host and port values from config.properties file that exist in the project for configured parameters.

Is it possible? How?

P.S. my project is in scala but I don't think this is different from Java project for the specific question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found in [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#_rabbitconnectionfactorybean_and_configuring_ssl) documentation, that it is possible by putting the config parameter in **${** configParameter **}**. As following:

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitConnectionFactory"    
                           host="${myproject.rabbitmq.connections.host}"
                           port="${myproject.rabbitmq.connections.port}"/>
```

In my case this is all I needed, but as the document show, you can add some other settings:

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitConnectionFactory"    
                           host="${host}"
                           port="${port}"
                           virtual-host="${vhost}"
                           username="${username}" password="${password}" />
```

I hope it will help some other people.